# Bash - How to loop through sub directories and copy in a file

Tags: bash, unix, copy

I'm new to coding in bash.

I'm trying to create something which will loop through all subdirectories, and within each one it should copy a file to that directory.

So for example, if I have the following directories

```
/dir1/  
/dir2/  
/dir3/  
...  
...  
/dirX/
```

And a file `fileToCopy.txt`

Then I want to run something which will open every single `/dirX` file and put `fileToCopy.txt` in that directory. Leaving me with:

```
/dir1/fileToCopy.txt
/dir2/fileToCopy.txt
/dir3/fileToCopy.txt
...
...
/dirX/fileToCopy.txt
```

I would like to do this in a loop, as then I am going to try to modify this loop to add some more steps, as ultimately the .txt file is actually a .java file, I am wanting to copy it into each directory, compile it (with the other classes in there), and run it to gather the output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for i in dir1, dir2, dir3, .., dirN
    do
        cp /home/user1068470/fileToCopy.txt $i
    done
```

Alternatively, you can use the following code.

```
for i in *
    do                 # Line breaks are important
        if [ -d $i ]   # Spaces are important
            then
                cp fileToCopy.txt $i
        fi
    done
```

Comment: Hi, for this method I need to know the names of all of the subdirectories? I was hoping it would be possible to just say:
Loop through all subdirectories of where I am now
Copy the file
Done

Or is this what this is actually doing? Thanks!

Comment: see the second part of my answer.

Comment: some minor things: spaces and quotes, namely `[ -d "$i" ]` and `cp fileToCopy.txt "$i"`

Answer (score 7):

Finds all directory under the current directory (.) and copies the file into them:

```
find . -type d -exec cp fileToCopy.txt '{}' \;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. This does work but I was hoping for something in a loop so that I could add some extra steps.

Comment: `find . -type d  -name "dir?" -exec cp fileToCopy.txt '{}' \;`

Comment: @sarathi, don't think you need `-name "dir?"` here since OP is looping through all subdirectories